# For x in string , how to check if x is last

Tags: python, string

Is there a way to know if x is the last element of a string in the following basic example of a for loop

```
for x in string_time:
     do something
```

Comment: is _equal_ to the last element?  or _is_ the last element?

Comment: I want it to know if it's the last element not equal to

Comment: if x == string_time[-1]

Comment: If you describe your full problem, there might be a simpler way than thinking about the last character separately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to know whether `x` is physically the last element in the string, you can use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for i,x in enumerate(string_time, start=1-len(string_time)):
    if not i:
        # last element
    ...
```

If, on the other hand, you want to know whether `x` is *equal* to the last element, you can simply use `==` (as was also mentioned in the comments):

```
for x in string_time:
    if x == string_time[-1]:
        # last element
    ...
```

---

Just to describe what's going on in the first snippet: we're enumerating the string starting at `1-len(string)`, which does the following:

```
>>> s = 'abc'
>>>
>>> list(enumerate(s, start=1-len(s)))
[(-2, 'a'), (-1, 'b'), (0, 'c')]
```

So the last element is enumerated with `0`, meaning we can use the `not i` check to check if we're on the last element.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to process the last character in the string separately from the loop

```
for x in string_time[:-1]:
    # do stuff
last_char = string_time[-1]
```

This assumes that the string is non-empty.